# SSH tunnelling into arch box

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel, x11-forwarding, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi running arch linux connected to the TV and want to run commands on that screen by SSH'ing from my Ubuntu machine elsewhere.

I have tried running the command SSH -Y root@ and starting xclock as a test. However I get the following error:

No protocol specified
Error: Can't open display: :0

I then tried running "export DISPLAY=:0" on the arch machine, but this doesn't solve the issue.

I have X running fine and can see it on the TV and I have edited the file /etc/ssh/ssh_config to allow X11 forwarding.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks

Comment: It looks like you want to start a program on a local machine and make it appear on a display connected to a remote machine. If so, `-Y` is not your friend. It's for doing things the other way around.

Comment: Oh I see, so if I SSH'd into the raspberry pi and ran the -Y command from there to my machine that would be better?

Comment: `ssh` to the remote machine, `export DISPLAY=:0` there, `ssh -Y` back, do **not** do `export DISPLAY`, run `xclock`. Provided you indeed have X running on `:0` on the remote machine, and the remote user can connect to it, this should work.

Comment: I SSH'd into the arch box, then ssh -Y'd back to my ubuntu machine to open a file on there using gedit, but instead of coming up on the arch screen, it simply opened the file on my ubuntu machine XD I also tried copying the file to the arch box then SSH -Y from ubuntu to arch, hoping the opposite would happen, but I got the same error as before...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ArchLinux wiki has [some good instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ssh#X11_Forwarding) on setting things up.  I struggled for a while until I found them, but for me the key was to set up SSH forwarding within sshd_config (most distros seem to enable this by default, but Arch doesn't).

Once you've enabled X forwarding in SSHD, I also found it helpful to install the dummy video driver for Xorg ("pacman -S xf86-video-dummy"), which gets rid of irritating errors about missing the RANDR extension.  This might not be necessary if you already have it running a real X server locally on the Pi - personally, I'm running mine completely headless.

I've found that I don't have to worry about setting up the DISPLAY variable, or xhost, when running with 'ssh -X' from an iMac.  I'd expect Ubuntu to behave the same.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, but I have been busy with work and have found other interesting ideas for the pi. However, your answer deserves recognition, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

looks like an authentication problem. The answer used to be

```
xhost +
```

on the console of the X display. Might help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to set

export DISPLAY=[IP_ADDRESS_OF_ARCH_BOX]:0

on your Ubuntu box, then when you run xclock from your Ubuntu box, it'll forward the screen to the Arch box.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, then SSH'd into the arch box using SSH -Y root@<IP> but I still get the error "Error: Can't open display: " =/